# List of unique values in a Column in XtraGrid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

[image]

Is there a way to get the list of unique values in any Column in XtraGrid. When I click on the column title for filtering, it shows the list (see the attached image '}' ).

Is there any XtraGrid object or Column object by which I can get this in form of array or list ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about you implement it as an extension method on the GridView like this

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid;

namespace Extensions
{
    public static class XtraGridExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<string> GetColumnsDistinctDisplayText(this GridView gv, string columnName)
        {
            if (gv == null)
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("GridView is null");
            }
            if (gv.RowCount == 0)
            {
                return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
            }
            return (from int row in Enumerable.Range(0, gv.RowCount - 1)
                    select gv.GetRowCellDisplayText(row, columnName)).Distinct().OrderBy(s => s);
        }
    }
}
```

and whenever you want to use it use it like this

```
using Extensions;

...

string msg = string.Empty;
foreach (var item in gridView1.GetColumnsDistinctDisplayText("columnName"))
{
    msg += item + "\n";
}
MessageBox.Show(msg);
```

Comment: I've implemented something like that but using the datasource and columnName.

Comment: @CodingBarfield The benefit of using the grid though is, if the user filtered the data, it will give you the unfiltered values only.

Comment: Thanks @JoelWeiss , it works for me, but I was wondering if there's already a collection of such values so that we don't have to loop through and do ".Distinct().OrderBy(s => s);"...

Comment: @EternalNoob As far as i know there isn't such a collection.